# How to add image in Sqlite database from phone gallery?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

This is my code to get data from gallery and save it in SQLite database but its not working

```
    .....

    case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:     
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        if (extras2 != null) {
            Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            // convert bitmap to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
            Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
            // Inserting Contacts
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addContact(new Contact(resultCode, "Android", imageInByte));
            Intent i = new Intent(Editor.this, Editor.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just store the uri/path of the image. no need to store entire image in database

Comment: Uri uri = data.getData(); Try this way.

Comment: You can't store the store the images in database, if you worry about the data loss(user may delete the image) then you can copy the image into the local data directory and store the image path in the database if needed

Answer (score 0):

**Store Uri of an Image, through Uri you can set an Image in ImageView**

```
   Uri imageUri;

   Intent pickUpImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            pickUpImage.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(pickUpImage, 1);

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            imageUri = uri;
            profilePic.setImageURI(imageUri);

        }
    }
```